# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Retail Sales' not found | otext - Forecasting: Principles and Practice

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression

I'm going over the otext Forecasting: Principles and Practice, and in chapter [7.1](https://otexts.com/fpp3/regression-intro.html), the author writes a simple code:

```
us_change %>%
  model(TSLM(Consumption ~ Income)) %>%
  report()
```

us_change data can be found through the fpp3 package [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fpp3/versions/0.4.0/topics/us_change).

I'm trying to apply this to my own data set using St. Louis economic data on [retail sales](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/RSXFSN) and [disposable income](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DSPIC96). I have a window on the series from Jan2013 - Jun2021 (in case anyone wants to reproduce *exactly* what I have). Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(report)
library(tsibble)
library(fpp3)
library(fable)

data("us_change")

rs <- read_excel("Retail Sales.xlsx",
                 sheet = "Retail Sales")

rdpi <- read_excel("RDPI.xlsx",
                   sheet = "RDPI - Edit")

us_change %>%
  model(TSLM(Consumption ~ Income)) %>%
  report()

z <- cbind(rs,rdpi)

# both data sets had a "Date" column
z <- z[, !duplicated(colnames(z))]

z <- z %>%
  as_tsibble(
    key = c(`Retail Sales`,RDPI),
    index = Date)

z <- z[order(z$Date),]

z %>%
  model(TSLM(`Retail Sales` ~ RDPI)) %>%
  report()
```

The last line produces "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Retail Sales' not found". So I ran

```
head(z)
class(us_change)
class(z)
class(us_change$Consumption)
class(z$`Retail Sales`)
"Retail Sales" %in% names(z)
```

which produces:

```
> head(z)
# A tsibble: 6 x 3 [?] <UTC>
# Key:       Retail Sales, RDPI [6]
  Date                `Retail Sales`   RDPI
  <dttm>                       <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00         333663 12259.
2 2013-02-01 00:00:00         332471 12225.
3 2013-03-01 00:00:00         374171 12262.
4 2013-04-01 00:00:00         362978 12299 
5 2013-05-01 00:00:00         389709 12359.
6 2013-06-01 00:00:00         369355 12362.
> class(us_change)
[1] "tbl_ts"     "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(z)
[1] "tbl_ts"     "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(us_change$Consumption)
[1] "numeric"
> class(z$`Retail Sales`)
[1] "numeric"
> "Retail Sales" %in% names(z)
[1] TRUE
```

They're the same class, and I verified that the retail sales column exists in z. What am I missing that's causing this error? I've been putting wrinkles on my forehead at this longer than I'd like to admit, so I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you made `Retail Sales` the key, it was no longer an option. If you set no parameters with `as_tsibble()` it will work fine.

```
z <- z %>% as_tsibble()

z %>%
  model(TSLM(`Retail Sales` ~ RDPI)) %>%
  report()
```

Comment: To add to this, key variables for a tsibble should be columns of the data that uniquely identify each time series. Sales and RDPI are known as measured variables - the things you're interested in looking at over time - and are not a key variable (such as product, or store).